# Searching in Alfresco in all tenants

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to search files, folders in Alfresco in all existing tenants? For example: I am admin user in the tenantA and would like find files in all other tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its possible to search files or folders in all existing alfresco tenants.As far as I know tenants are designed for hiding visibility of document from one to another tenants.That is the main purpose for which tenant were introduced.

So that single alfresco instance can be used for more than one organization,without knowing that another user is also using same instance for document management.

You can find more about tenant on below link.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Multi-Tenancy

Comment: I am curious about ,why you would like to do this?

Comment: We have some hidden sites in each tenants with predefined structured folders. That used as a template for creating new sites. So now I looking how to possible searching in that sites in all tenants.